# How does one create a scrollview with buttons without interfering with scrolling?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

How does one create a scrollview with buttons, without interfering with scrolling ?

I am trying to create a “toolbar”, by creating a scrollview(that scrolls only horizontally) and adding various “buttons” to it.

Things are fine when the scrollview does not contain any buttons - I can scroll easily to my hearts content! The problem is when I start adding buttons!

If my finger makes contact with an area where there is no button - then I can scroll without problem.

But if my finger makes contact with an area where there is a button, then dragging does not make the scrollview scroll! Instead the button seems to “absorb” the touch and registers it as a “cancelled” button press!

How do I modify my code, so I can scroll without the buttons interfering?

Here is my code:

```
        _mainToolbar = ui::ScrollView::create();
        _mainToolbar->setBounceEnabled(false);
        _mainToolbar->setDirection(ui::ScrollView::Direction::HORIZONTAL);
        _mainToolbar->setScrollBarPositionFromCorner(Vec2(4, 4));

    //…..

            ui::Button* button = ui::Button::create(imageName,"","",ui::Widget::TextureResType::PLIST);

            buttonSize = button->getContentSize();
            button->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5, 0.5));
            button->setTouchEnabled(true);
            button->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(Main::receiveButtonPressEvent, this));
            button->setSwallowTouches(true);

   // …

         _mainToolbar->addChild(button);


//…..


        _mainToolbar->setContentSize(mainToolContentSize);
        _mainToolbar->setInnerContainerSize(mainToolbarInnerContainerSize);

//….

void receiveButtonPressEvent(Ref *pSender,ui::Widget::TouchEventType type){          
    switch (type) {
        case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::BEGAN:{
            break;
        }

        case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::MOVED:{
            break;
        }

        case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED:{
            //Some code here if the button is pressed…”
            break;
        }

        case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::CANCELED:{
            break;
        }

        default:{
            break;
        }
    }//End switch(type)
}
```

EDIT: I have looked at the CPP tests, but in the tests, the buttons don't do anything - they don't have any touch event listeners, so they don't seem to interfere. I think this is where my problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this line

```
 button->setSwallowTouches(true);
```

change to

```
 button->setSwallowTouches(false);
```